# Error on close button with onclick javascript, maybe around quotes/single/double

Tags: javascript

I have a small Issue Tracker which uses a couple of functions to save and fetch issues to localStorage, all of which works fine, using the Chance uid generator to generate ids. However on making a third function to set the status to closed after getting the id which was generated previously. In console I get an error as below.

```
(function(event){setStatusClosed(fdf7622a-8738-5384-98b6-9ff9c47b2be0)
}) invalid or unexpected token. index.html:1
```

It's using onclick to run the function via the close button generated in the fetchIssues() function.

The first 2 functions fetchIssues() and saveIssues() have been working as expected with no errors and correctly converting the array to JSON object on push and back to array on retrieve, but when I try the setStatusClosed function I get the error. I also get similar errors when using other uid generator methods so I decided to stick with Chance. I can't seem to find the error and the log just points me to the event as pasted above. The code is below

```
/*jslint browser:true */

//Fetch submitted issues or the status of localStorage
function fetchIssues() {
     "use strict";       
var i = 0;
var issues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("issues"));
var issueList = document.querySelector('#issueList');

    issueList.innerHTML = " ";

if(issues !== null) {
    for(i = 0; i < issues.length; i++) {
    var id = issues[i].id,
        desc = issues[i].description,
        severity = issues[i].severity,
        assignedTo = issues[i].assignedTo,
        status = issues[i].status;

        issueList.innerHTML += "<div class='well'>" +
                        "<h6>Issue ID: " + id + "</h6>" +
                        "<p><span class='Label label-info'>" + status + "</span></p>" +
                        "<h3>" + desc + "</h3>" +
                        "<p><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-time'></span>" + severity + "</p>" +
                        "<p><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-user'></span>" + assignedTo + "</p>" +
                        "<a href='#' onclick='setStatusClosed("+ id +")' class='btn btn-warning'>Close</a>" +
                        "<a href='#' onclick='deleteIssue(" + id + ")' class='btn btn-danger'>Delete</a>" +
                        "</div>";
}
console.log(issues);
} else {
issueList.innerHTML = "<h6 class='text-center'>There are no issues at present</h6>";    
}
}

//Save a submitted issue
function saveIssue(e) {
    "use strict";
var chance = new Chance();
var issueDesc = document.querySelector("#issueDescInput").value,
    issueSeverity = document.querySelector("#issueSeverityInput").value,
    issueAssignedTo = document.querySelector("#issueAssignedToInput").value,
    issueStatus = "Open",
    issueId = chance.guid(),
    issues = [],
    issue = {
    id: issueId,
    description: issueDesc,
    severity: issueSeverity,
    assignedTo: issueAssignedTo,
    status: issueStatus
};
//Check if entry already there
if(localStorage.getItem("issues") === null) {
//Push the issue object to issues array
issues.push(issue);
//Set the new issues array as a converted JSON object to localStorage
localStorage.setItem("issues", JSON.stringify(issues));
} else {
//Request the issues object and convert to array
issues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("issues"));
//Push new object to issues array
issues.push(issue);
//Set the new issues array as a converted JSON object to localStorage
localStorage.setItem("issues", JSON.stringify(issues));
}
//Reset submit element
document.querySelector("#issueInputForm").reset();
//Run fetchIssue to reflect the new item
fetchIssues();
//Stop default submit
e.preventDefault();
}
//Submit event for the saveIssue function
document.querySelector("#issueInputForm").addEventListener("submit", saveIssue);

//Set the issue status to closed
function setStatusClosed(id) {
var i;
var issues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("issues"));
for(i = 0; i < issues.length; i++) {
    if(issues[i].id == id) {
        issues.status = "Closed";
    }
}
localStorage.setItem("issues", JSON.stringify(issues));
fetchIssues();
}
```

It all compiles fine in  the [Closure compiler](https://closure-compiler.appspot.com/)

[image]

The error appears only when hitting the close issue button, so does anyone know why the function is not being properly called in the onclick event (generated via innerHTML method) ?

Any tips welcome, Thanks

Update, I have tried altering the call in the generated innerHTML to escape the quotes but now I get a slightly different error that setStatusClosed() is not defined for the onclick event.(Also I removed Bootstrap so its just using the lib js file.), so there seems to be an error with the onclick call.

```
issueList.innerHTML += '<div class="well">' +
                        '<h6>Issue ID: ' + id + '</h6>' +
                        '<p><span class="Label label-info">' + status + '</span></p>' +
                        '<h4>' + desc + '</h4>' +
                        '<p><span class="icon icon-clock"></span> ' + severity + '</p>' +
                        '<p><span class="icon icon-user"></span> ' + assignedTo + '</p>' +
                        '<a href="#" onclick="setStatusClosed(\''+ id +'\')" class="button button-outline">Close</a>' +
                        '<a href="#"" onclick="deleteIssue(\''+ id +'\')" class="button">Delete</a>' +
                        '</div>';
```

[image]

Comment: have you tried adding quotes around the GUID when calling the function?
 setStatusClosed('fdf7622a-8738-5384-98b6-9ff9c47b2be0');

Comment: Yes tried that, I get a slightly different error now, see above, Many Thanks